# onSaveInstanceState is called as soon as app starts

Tags: android

as soon as all data is read from memory or new data is set, onSaveInstanceState is called.
i put Log.e calls at the beginning of each function to see what is called just before onSaveInstanceState is called.

what is causing the program to end?
some times i have to click on power button, to be able to move the unlock button, sometime it will move without having to push the power button.

using eclipse to test.
kind of works in simulator, crashes on phone.

don't know what else to add.

found this after a few functions were called:
GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC   freed   1K, 45% free    3339K/6023K,    external    5407K/6752K,    paused  87ms
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC   freed   5K, 45% free    3344K/6023K,    external    7110K/7462K,    paused  81ms
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC   freed   11K,    45% free    3356K/6023K,    external    7982K/8032K,    paused  106ms
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate
Initializing    inflate state
Initializing    zlib    to  inflate

looks to me like some kind of loop

```
@Override  
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {        
        //Store the game state  
        Log.e("onSaveInstanceState", " public void onSaveInstanceState");
        // ?? replace   
        // ?? is called when answer phone button is pushed    
        // ?? is called when red phone button is pushed   
        // ?? is called when house button is pushed   
        // ?? is called when power button is pushed
        // ?? "outState.putBundle" does not seem to do anything
        outState.putBundle(m_MyView.GetFileName(), 
                m_MyView.m_prRecord.SaveBundleData());


    }

{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try
        {
            Log.e("onCreate", "onCreate");
            //Debug.startMethodTracing("calc");
            //System.gc();

            setContentView(R.layout.main_Layout);

            PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(
                    this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null));

            m_MyView = (CMyView) findViewById(R.id.main);  
            m_MyView.SetTextView((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text));  

            Log.e("onCreate", "savedInstanceState == null " + (savedInstanceState == null));


            m_MyView.SetPopup(popup);
            // [breaks code]
            //popup.setContentView((CMenu) findViewById(R.id.menuView)); 

            if(savedInstanceState != null)
            {
                LoadBundleData(savedInstanceState);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    // ?? check if we have a saved file
                    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(m_MyView.GetFileName() );
                    Log.e("onCreate", "fis == null " + (fis == null));
                    // ?? if fis == null then exception is thrown
                    // ?? if statement is used to remove unused variable error
                    if(fis != null)
                    {
                        if(m_MyView.m_prRecord.LoadByteData(
                                m_MyView.GetFileName()) == false)
                        {
                            Log.e("onCreate", "new");
                            // ?? all data was not loaded
                            m_MyView.SetMode(CMyView.NEW);
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.e("onCreate", "got here");
                            m_MyView.SetMode(CMyView.READY);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    // ?? if(fis == null) is dead code
                    /*else
                    {
                        //Log.e("onCreate", "fis == null");
                        m_MyView.setMode(CMyView.NEW);
                    }
                    */
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    //Log.e("onCreate", "Exception 1");
                    // We were just launched -- set up a new game
                    // ?? which means we need to make a Stream file to write to
                    //Log.e("onCreate", "ERROR IN public void onCreate: " + 
                        //  e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    m_MyView.SetMode(CMyView.NEW);
                }

            }
            //Debug.stopMethodTracing();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Log.e("onCreate", "Exception 2");
            // this is the line of code that sends a real error message to the log
            //Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN public void onCreate: " + e.toString());

            // this is the line that prints out the location in
            // the code where the error occurred.
            //e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}
```

---

now i am utterly confused.
i added:

```
 @Override
    public void onResume()
    public void onRestart()
     public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
with this inside:
    {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e("onResume", "enter");
    }
```

onResume is called, but onSaveInstanceState is not called.

?? how can override and pass through of 3 function keep another function from being called?

?? ran it two more times, and onSaveInstanceState showed up AFTER onResume.
onResume -> onSaveInstanceState -> onPause -> onDraw

Comment: put some code to get help

Comment: how you are using `saveInstanceState` might be the problem.
put some code so we can help

Comment: if i knew what code to post, i most likely what not be asking the question. other than posting the whole project. from what i can track down sofar, the program finishes onCreate then jumps to onSaveInstanceState

Comment: ?? why would what one codes in a function effect how or why something else calls it?

Comment: after onSaveInstanceState, and data is saved, then onDraw is called. why?

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) says:

> This method is called before an activity **may be killed** so that when it comes back some time in the future it can restore its state.

So if this method is called it doesn't mean that your activity will be always killed. For that you have the `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` methods, so make sure that you save your info in `onSaveInstanceState()` and to restore in the proper method.

Comment: wonder if using threads would keep the activity from "may be killed" or half killed.

Comment: The philosophy here is that you don't have to worry about that, just make sure that you save your data in that method and to restore it when the app is recreated.

Comment: it is not getting recreated. it starts then stops.

Comment: it is not getting recreated. it starts then stops. onCreate -> data loaded -> onResume -> onSaveInstanceState -> onPause -> onDraw. looking for other functions to override to see if they are called. something is causing the program to stop as soon as it starts or as it is starting.